# Getting error on console despite handling it (MERN + Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, axios

I am sending axios get request whose end-point sends the user associated with the token stored in localStorage and then the redux state is updated with the user. When I don't have a token the end-point return a res with status 401 with message "Unauthorized" and then I handle it in the catch statement and set the "error" redux state. But even after doing this the error is displayed on the console like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) /users/auth:1
```

This is the function which makes api call and authorizes the user:

```
export function loadUser(){
return function (dispatch,getState){
    dispatch(userLoading());
    const token = getState().auth.token;
    const config = {
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        }
    }
    if(token) config.headers['auth-token']=token;
    axios.get('http://localhost:80/users/auth',config)
    .then(user => {
        dispatch(clearError())
        dispatch(userLoaded(user.data))
    })
    .catch(error => {
        dispatch(setError(error.response.status,error.response.data.msg));
        dispatch(authError());
    })
}
```

}

This is the middleware which handles the token before hitting the endpoint (In my case response is returned from here itself since there is no token sent):

```
function auth(req,res,next){
    const token = req.header('auth-token');
    if(!token) res.status(401).json({msg:"Unauthorized"})
    else{

        try{
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token,jwt_secret);
            req.user = decoded;
            next();
        }
        catch(e){
            res.status(400).json({msg:"Invalid token"})
        }

    }
}
```

I'm not able to figure out why am I getting error on console (State is getting updated as desired)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually impossible to do with JavaScript. because of security concerns and a potential for a script to hide its activity from the user.

The best you can do is clearing them from your console.

```
 console.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are not getting the token when consulting your API.
If this is the case I recommend you use defaults.headers.common in this way

```
const axiosApi = axios.create({ baseURL: "http://localhost:80" });

const headerAuth = () => {
  const token = getMyToken();
  if (token) {
    axiosApi.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  } else {
    delete axiosApi.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
  }
};

export function loadUser(){
  headerAuth(); // <----- 
  return function (dispatch,getState){
    dispatch(userLoading());
    axiosApi.get('/users/auth',config)
    .then(user => {
      dispatch(clearError())
      dispatch(userLoaded(user.data))
     })
     .catch(error => {
       dispatch(setError(error.response.status,error.response.data.msg));
       dispatch(authError());
     })
   }
```

I recommend that you do not store the token in the REDUX but in sessionStorage

Comment: Receiving token and authenticating the user based on the token works fine. Only thing is it shows the error which I sent from the End point on the console even though I handled it in axios.catch to update error state in redux store